# How to fix this SQLAlchemy case?

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Using SQLAlchemy, I am trying to calculate a percentage in the SELECT section of a query -  precisely, the percentage of shares owned by a shareholder.

```py
# The total amount of shares.
total_share_amount = session.query( Share ).count()

# The subquery of shares selection: contains the shares' price and amount.
shares_subq = session.query( 
    func.count( Share.share_number ).label('shares_count'),
    Share.account_nb,
    func.sum( Share.latest_price ).label('latest_price'),
).group_by( Share.account_nb ).subquery()

# The query of shareholders selection, containing...
q = session.query(

    # ... Basic shareholder info...
    Shareholder.account_nb, 
    Shareholder.first_name,
    Shareholder.last_name,

    # ... Its full amount of shares...
    shares_subq.c.shares_count,

    # ... Its percentage of shares...
    case( #FIXME Does not work! Result return is always 0.
        [( total_share_amount == 0, 0 )], 
        else_ = label('my_indicator', ( shares_subq.c.shares_count / total_share_amount ) * 100 )
    ).label('shares_percent'),

    # ... The full value of the shares.
    shares_subq.c.latest_price.label('shares_value')
).join( shares_subq, shares_subq.c.account_nb == Shareholder.account_nb, isouter = True )
```

Here, I first get the full amount of shares using the result of an initial query (`total_share_amount`). In the problematic `case` section, I wish to return a percentage of 0 only if there are no shares in the base - otherwise, the actual percentage owned by the shareholder. But the query always returns a `shares_percent` of 0 even there are shares in the base and shareholders own them.

I assume it is an issue of syntax?

Answer (score 0):

What is the data type of your columns?

Seems likely that shares_count is an integer, which means that your division will always return 0. You will need to CAST one of your values in the `else` statement to work.

Also, "total_share_amount" is a constant in your code (since you pull it with a separate request). You don't need any of that sql logic there (unless you meant to use "total_share_amount" as a subquery or similar)